# Cant connect to sql database using xampp as local server

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a problem connecting to sql database:

[image]

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $myDB = "udemy";


    // Create connection
    $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $myDB );

    if (mysqli_connect_error()){

        die ("There was an error connecting to the database");
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

    if (mysqli_query($link, $query)){

        echo "Query was successfull"

    }   

?>
```

Error is showing when I try to connect database named "udemy"...

Comment: what is your database username and password ? is it blank ?

Comment: Give `username:"root"` where you are passing username

Comment: Set the username and password

Comment: Why do you expect that we know why your mysql server refuses a connection without username and password?

Comment: Set username and password or add a new user in your mysql  server and try with those user details.

Comment: i dont have user and password

Comment: UPDATE mysql.user SET user='newusername',
 password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE user='root';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: @TrenceAngov Please review my answer below and accept and up-vote if helped.

Answer (score 0):

Set username and password or add a new user in your mysql server and try with those user details.

To create new user :-

To create user in MySQL/MariaDB 5.7.6 and higher, use [CREATE USER syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html):

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

then to grant all access to the database (e.g. my_db), use [GRANT Syntax, e.g.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db.* TO 'new_user'@'localhost';
```

Where ALL (priv_type) can be replaced with specific privilege such as

```
SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, ALTER etc
```

Then to reload newly assigned permissions run:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now set newly created username and password in your code.

Hope it helped.